# Skipping old code from code validation in sonar

Tags: validation, svn, code-coverage, sonarqube

We have a scenario where we got a .net project and it has some old code.

Now, we started implementing sonar code validation on this and unfortunately we got many validation issues from old code which is not written by us.

So, as per the agreement we are not supposed tho fix those issues.

Old and current code is available in SVN repository.

Is there any posssiblity to skip the old code based on SVN revision and performing the code validation only on the top of baseline changes?

Comment: Dit you ever find a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The only good way to do that for the moment is to:

- analyze your existing code base in SonarQube
- set a version on it (in "Project Configuration > History"), e.g. "BASE_LINE"
- specify this version in the differential periods so that all your upcoming analyses are compared to this baseline

Comment: Actually we have tried to baseline the code and remove the existing issues by marking the issues as false positing using the following queries. USE XYZ

                SELECT [id]
,[kee]
        ,[component_id]
,[root_component_id]      
        ,[status]
,[resolution]        
                 FROM [XYZ].[dbo].[issues] where  [root_component_id]= 64421 and  status = 'OPEN' 
                 GO

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Update query

USE XYZ

go begin transaction

UPDATE [XYZ].[dbo].[issues] SET
[status] = 'RESOLVED' ,[resolution] = 'FALSE-POSITIVE'

WHERE [root_component_id]= 64421 and status='OPEN' rollback transaction
GO


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

UPDATE [XYZ].[dbo].[issues] SET
[status] = 'RESOLVED' ,[resolution] = 'FALSE-POSITIVE'

WHERE [root_component_id]= 64421 and status='OPEN' 


------------------------------------------------------------------------

This will make all the records status as 'RESOLVED' and resolution as 'FALSE-POSITIVE'.

Comment: However, if the old file is modified, instead of doing code coverage for the new code, it is publishing the issues for old code as well in that file.

Comment: So, I think there would be another way to baseline the code, so that even though the old files are modified, it will perform the code coverage only on top of baseline. Is there any alternate way available using SVN revision numbers and baselining the code.

Answer (score 0):

This page from the SonarQube documentation might help http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus

Answer (score 0):

Actually we have tried to baseline the code and remove the existing issues by marking the issues as false positing using the following queries.
USE XYZ

```
                SELECT [id]
,[kee]
        ,[component_id]
,[root_component_id]      
        ,[status]
,[resolution]        
                 FROM [XYZ].[dbo].[issues] where  [root_component_id]= 64421 and  status = 'OPEN' 
                 GO
```

---

Update query

USE XYZ

go
 begin transaction

UPDATE [XYZ].[dbo].[issues]
     SET
       [status] = 'RESOLVED'
       ,[resolution] = 'FALSE-POSITIVE'

WHERE  [root_component_id]= 64421 and status='OPEN' 
      rollback transaction
      GO

---

UPDATE [XYZ].[dbo].[issues]
     SET
       [status] = 'RESOLVED'
       ,[resolution] = 'FALSE-POSITIVE'

WHERE  [root_component_id]= 64421 and status='OPEN'

---

This will make all the records status as 'RESOLVED' and resolution as 'FALSE-POSITIVE'.

However, if the old file is modified, instead of doing code coverage for the new code, it is publishing the issues for old code as well  in that file.

So, I think there would be another way to baseline the code, so that even though the old files are modified, it will perform the code coverage only on top of baseline. Is there any alternate way available using SVN revision numbers and baselining the code.

Comment: This (no longer) seems to work (the get changed back) did you find another solution by any chance?