# Skip Legacy code in sonar code validation

Tags: svn, sonarqube

We have a scenario where we got a .net project and it has some legacy code.

Now, we started implementing sonar code validation on this and unfortunately we got many validation issues from legacy code which is not written by us.

So, as per the agreement, we are not supposed to fix those issues.

Legacy and current code is available in SVN repository.

Is there any posssiblity to skip the legacy code based on SVN revision and performing the code validation only on the top of baseline changes?

Actually we have tried to baseline the code and remove the existing issues by marking the issues as false positing using the following queries.

```
USE XYZ 
SELECT [id] ,[kee] ,[component_id] ,[root_component_id] ,[status] ,[resolution] FROM [XYZ].[dbo].[issues] where [root_component_id]= 64421 and status = 'OPEN' GO ---- 

Update query 
USE XYZ 
go begin transaction UPDATE [XYZ].[dbo].[issues] SET [status] = 'RESOLVED' ,[resolution] = 'FALSE-POSITIVE' WHERE [root_component_id]= 64421 and status='OPEN' rollback transaction GO -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- UPDATE [XYZ].[dbo].[issues] SET [status] = 'RESOLVED' ,[resolution] = 'FALSE-POSITIVE' WHERE [root_component_id]= 64421 and status='OPEN' ------------------------------------------------------------------------ This will make all the records status as 'RESOLVED' and resolution as 'FALSE-POSITIVE'.
```

However, if the old file is modified, instead of doing code coverage only for the new code, it is publishing the issues for old code as well in that file.

So, I think there would be another way to baseline the code, so that even though the old files are modified, it will perform the code coverage only on top of baseline. Is there any alternate way available using SVN revision numbers and baselining the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skipping old code from code validation in sonar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053453/skipping-old-code-from-code-validation-in-sonar)

Comment: Still I have this issue and Is there any possiblity to skip the legacy code.